# "Differentiating", "distinguishing," or another word for "that helps to tell apart easily"?

Tags: word-choice

I am trying to come up with the right word that means *that helps to tell apart easily*, for example, one that fits into the following sentences:

- Beak shape is a ***_*_** feature among birds.
- Language is usually the **__** feature for ethnic groups.

I tried *differentiating* and *distinguishing*, but was not quite sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [standard word](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=differentiating%20feature,distinguishing%20feature&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) in this context is *distinguishing*...

[image]

In principle, as OP suspects, *differentiating* ought to be useable in this context, but it just isn't. Apart from anything else, *differentiation* has largely been appropriated by the mathematicians.

For many decades, many linguists have worked within the framework of [Distinctive Feature Theory](https://www.msu.edu/course/asc/232/DF/df-theory.html), but that's a bit specialised. And in general parlance we often refer to the *distinctive features* of all sorts of things, but by that we normally mean features which are particularly noticeable, rather than features which are crucial to identifying exactly what we're looking at.

Also [identifying features](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=identifying%20features&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), which for some reason seem to be more associated with contexts outside biology/taxonomy. All these terms (less commonly) occur with [characteristic](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=identifying%20feature,identifying%20characteristic,distinguishing%20characteristic,distinguishing%20feature&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) instead of *feature*.

Answer (score 2):

*[Discriminative](http://freedictionary.org/?Query=discriminative)* and *[discriminating](http://freedictionary.org/?Query=discriminating)* are also valid.

Comment: Technically speaking they're valid, but I get the impression [from NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=discriminating+features%2Cdiscriminative+features&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) that *discriminating features* died out by the mid-1800s. To the extent that either word occurs with *features* today, it seems to me most of the writers are non-native speakers - a goodly number of them having names that look Indian.

Comment: @Fumble, I think your post quite clearly shows what to use, but mine was in reply to the "or another word" part.

Comment: Yeah, I agree they're semantically okay. To an extent *discriminating* is used with the same sense as *discerning*, but it has the "differentiating" sense too. And *discriminative* sounds dated to me, but I wouldn't call it archaic. And there's the new kid on the block - [identifying features](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=identifying+features&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: @Fumble I agree. I think discriminating features is practically more likely to be used to describe features that are able to discriminate, as in "The enhanced discriminating features of the upgraded AIM-9 missile allow it to be effective against modern infrared countermeasures."

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, 'Beak shape is a characteristic feature among birds' seems to fit well. You could as well use the word 'individualizing'.

Answer (score -2):

I'm fond of *discernible/discerning* myself.

Comment: I do not believe those mean what you think they do.  *Discernible* is akin to *perceivable* or *detectable*, while *discerning* means "showing good or outstanding judgment and understanding" (dictionary.com).